# Python Script immediately closes when ran as sudo

Tags: python, linux, sudo, raspberry-pi4

I wrote a python script, which pings a server using `ping3`.
Since this requires root permissions in order to function, I ran the script as sudo.

Now the thing is, when I run the program without sudo, it stays open, but if ran as sudo, it immediately closes, without any exceptions.

My script:

```
import atexit
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread

import ping3
from ping3 import ping
from phue import Bridge
from datetime import datetime

ping3.EXCEPTIONS = False

functionOne = 13
functionTwo = 15
functionThree = 16
relaisStörung = 18

functionOneState = False
functionTwoState = False
errorState = False


def handleExit():
    gpio.cleanup()
    print('EXITED! ', hueLogic.getCurrentDateTime())
    sys.exit(0)


class NetworkWatchdog(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        # Call the Thread class's init function
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global errorState
        routerAddress = '192.168.178.1'
        errorCounter = 0
        while 1:
            result = ping(routerAddress)
            if not result or result is None:
                errorCounter = + 1
            else:
                errorCounter = 0
            if errorCounter > 1:
                print('Netzwerk Fehler! Stör Relay an! ', hueLogic.getCurrentDateTime())
                errorState = True
                gpio.output(relaisStörung, gpio.HIGH)
            elif errorCounter < 1:
                if errorState:
                    print("Netzwerk Fehler behoben! Stör Relay normal! ", hueLogic.getCurrentDateTime())
                    errorState = False
                    gpio.output(relaisStörung, gpio.LOW)
            time.sleep(2)



# sys.stdout = open('/home/admin/Desktop/log.log', 'a+')
# sys.stderr = open('/home/admin/Desktop/log.log', 'a+')
atexit.register(handleExit)
hueLogic = HueLogic()
watchDog = NetworkWatchdog()
watchDog.daemon = True
watchDog.start()
print("--------------------------------")
print("Programm started! ", hueLogic.getCurrentDateTime())

gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(functionOne, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)
gpio.setup(functionTwo, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)
gpio.setup(functionThree, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)
gpio.setup(relaisStörung, gpio.OUT)
# relais default on
gpio.output(relaisStörung, gpio.LOW)

gpio.add_event_detect(functionOne, gpio.BOTH, callback=hueLogic.functionOne, bouncetime=500)
gpio.add_event_detect(functionTwo, gpio.BOTH, callback=hueLogic.functionTwo, bouncetime=500)
gpio.add_event_detect(functionThree, gpio.BOTH, callback=hueLogic.functionThree, bouncetime=500)
```

Now my question is, why does this happen and if the solution is as simple as adding a while True loop at the end?

Answer (score 0):

make sure u excute

```
$sudo python main.py
```

instead of

```
$sudo main.py
```

also try to add

```
$chmod +x myscript.py
```

Comment: I did indeed try "sudo python3 main.py" but it closed. What does the 3rd solution do?

Comment: If your main.py file starts with a `#! /usr/bin/env python` shebang line, then the chmod is helpful, otherwise it isn't. The shebang lets you optionally omit the middle part of your invocation command, so "sudo ./main.py" will work just the same.

Comment: Please make sure to write your answers in proper English, don't use abbreviations like 'u', 'bcs' and so on. Note that this may be especially harder to read for some non-native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `$ sudo cmd` instead of `$ cmd`, several
things are different.
Definitely the uid reported by `$ id` will be different.
But your `$PATH` is likely different, as well,
and that's not the only env var that may change.

Insert a call to `breakpoint()` to let you
isolate *which* of those many python statements
is the one that causes trouble.
Use the `l` list and `n` next commands
to identify where you are in the execution so far.

Use commands like `$ sudo which python`
and `$ sudo python -m site` to verify
that you're running the expected
version of interpreter and imported libraries.

---

Here is a generic way of assessing how
your user & root env vars differ.

```
$      env | sort > /tmp/user.txt
$
$ sudo env | sort > /tmp/root.txt
$
$ diff -u /tmp/{user,root}.txt
```

It is possible that when running
as a root user you will need to
`conda activate myproject`,
or similarly activate venv.
There might be a .bashrc file
you want to `source`.

---

Pay careful attention to `PYTHONPATH` -- it's
a pretty important env var!
It controls the value of `sys.path`,
which matters for each of your `import` statements.